# PHP: str_replace acts weirdly

Tags: php, str-replace

I have php script that reads RSS feed from a website, and then modifies it a little
to fit better for my purposes. However, there is little thing that really annoys me:
I try to replace all `</p>` tags with little longer code with `</p>` at end of it, but 
str_replace just adds my code after it, with `<p></p>` following it.

Here is my code:

```
$feed = str_replace('</p>', '<div id="vote">'.$nOStars.'</div></p>', $feed);
```

And $nOStars contains following:

```
<img id="vote0" src="/images/imgStar.png" title="text">
<img id="vote1" src="/images/imgStar.png" title="text">           
<img id="vote2" src="/images/imgStar.png" title="text">
<img id="vote3" src="/images/imgStarEmpty.png" title="text">    
<img id="vote4" src="/images/imgStarEmpty.png" title="text">
```

EDIT: I just noticed that Internet Explorer does it right, but other browsers won't.

Comment: ...so it's not really related to str_replace or PHP at all. You just have HTML issues.

Comment: actully IE does it wrong, the other browser s are following the standards.

Answer (score 3):

PHP is doing it? I think your browser is.

For proof, try View Source instead of Inspect Element.

`<div>` is not a valid child of `<p>`. Restructure your HTML, maybe use `<span>` instead?.

Comment: Thank you, previously I used to put div after paragraph, and didn't thought that when changed the order.